# Most efficient way to execute php mail script looping through 100s of records

Tags: php, email, command-line, timeout, performance

I have a mailing script which loops through approx 900 subscribers (in database), building an individual email for each subscriber and sending via SMTP. This script is fired manually via the browser, however the number of records involved have resulted in the script starting to time out part way through. In tests, the error is almost always Fatal Error max execution time exceeded (although one time there was an error related to mail() and SMTP). I'm thinking that I should probably be running this type of script from the command line, however, the script still needs to be triggered manually (via a CMS admin user) - does anyone have any suggestions for a good way to handle this?

Comment: Run it in the background as a forked process with a longer max execution time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the timeout for a PHP script from within the script.

However, I'd rather use CRON+PHP-CLI based solution. The PHP code remains the same whether you use CGI or CLI, however, in CLI mode there is no implicit time limit.

Comment: CRON job will not be much help if this should be executed manually.

Comment: In that case you can "fork" the php-cli after the user is done with the manual part (e.g. the choosing the recipients). See [Running a Background Process from PHP on Linux](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-background-process-in-php.html)

Comment: it is! you manually create a "tasklist" and the cronjob fires every 2 minutes and sends out the first 10 mails in the list (numbers random)

Answer (score 1):

Tweeking the run time limit will only temporarily defer the problem.

You didn't say what OS this is running on - certainly if you've got a local MTA that may help, but the right solution would be to spawn a seperate process. Note that there are a number of pitfalls in this approach - see [this post](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html) for details of how to do it correctly on Unix type systems.

Comment: thanks, I'm running CentOS, so that link was very useful. I'm just trying to figure out how to trigger an existing daemon to start the mail script, e.g how can i execute this command following the initial user input which apache handles -> print `echo /usr/bin/php -q mailer.php | at now`;

Answer (score 0):

set_time_limit (0); should do the trick.

There is not much to say about more efficient way, unless we see your code....

Answer (score 0):

work with [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and every time the cron executes the script it can send a small amount of mails.

For example the Typo3 [mailer engine](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/direct_mail/2.2.0/view/3/1/) is invoked every 5 minutes and will check if any mails need to be sent.

So the user doesnt manually trigger the mailing script. The user only marks a newsletter which should be send by the mailer engine.